# Find the probability of getting the second ace as the $n^{th}$ card is picked from $52$ cards.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Cards are drawn one by one at random from a well shuffled full pack of $52$ cards. Find the probability of  the second ace being the $n^{th}$ card.

For this what I did was, for the $n-1^{th}$ positions, we need to make a selection of $n-2$ card from $48$ cards and then choose $1$ ace out of $4$. This can be done in $^{48}C_{n-2} × 4$ . Now for $n^{th}$ position, I can have an ace in $3$ ways. So total no of favourable case is $^{48}C_{n-2} × 4× 3$. For total cases I select n card from  $52$ in $^{52}C_{n}$. So $$P=\frac{^{48}C_{n-2} × 4× 3}{^{52}C_{n}}$$

But this is not quite the answer.  The answer instead is $$P=\frac{^{48}C_{n-2} ×\color{red}{n} × 4× 3}{^{52}C_{n}}$$, which is quite similar but differs only by an $n$ . Can someone please explain what have I missed.

Comment: Your title differs from the question in the body.  The title states that the second ace is picked *after* the $n$th card is selected, while the body indicates that the second case is the $n$th card that is picked.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You are right, I apologise, I have corrected this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $^{52}C_4$ possible sets of four positions in the deck where the four aces may be located. We can take this as a uniform sample space.

Then the question becomes, what is the probability that after taking a sample from this sample space, position $n$ will be one of the four positions selected, one position will be before $n,$ and the other two will be after $n$?

There is only one way to select position $n,$ but there are $^{n-1}C_1 = n-1$ ways to choose one position before $n$ and 
$^{52-n}C_2 = \frac{(52-n)!}{2!(50-n)!} = \frac{(52-n)(51-n)}{2}$ ways to choose two positions after $n.$
So the probability should be
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{{^{n-1}C_1} {^{52-n}C_2}}{^{52}C_4}\\[.5ex]
&= \frac{(n-1)\dfrac{(52-n)(51-n)}{2}}{\dfrac{52!}{4!48!}}\\[.5ex]
&= \frac{4!48!(n-1)(52-n)(51-n)}{2\cdot52!}\\[.5ex]
&= \frac{4\cdot3(n-1)(52-n)(51-n)}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}.
\end{align}

On the other hand,
\begin{align}
\frac{^{48}C_{n-2}\cdot4\cdot3}{^{52}C_{n}} &=
\frac{\left(\dfrac{48!}{(n-2)!(50-n)!}\right)\cdot4\cdot3}
     {\left(\dfrac{52!}{n!(52-n)!}\right)} \\[.3ex]
&= \frac{4\cdot3\cdot48!n!(52-n)!}{52!(n-2)!(50-n)!}\\
&= \frac{4\cdot3n(n-1)(52-n)(51-n)}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}.
\end{align}

This differs by a factor of $n$ from the result I got, but it's $n$ times **larger** than my result. If it gets multiplied by $n$ again, as in the formula that you say is supposed to be the "correct" answer, it would be wrong by a factor of $n^2$ according to my calculations.

Let's try this for $n=2.$ What is the probability that the second ace will be the second card? It's just the probability that the first two cards are both aces, which is
$$ P_2 = \frac{4\cdot3}{52\cdot51}.$$

Now observe that if $n=2,$ then
\begin{align}
\frac{4\cdot3(n-1)(52-n)(51-n)}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}
&= \frac{4\cdot3(2-1)(52-2)(51-2)}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}\\
&= \frac{4\cdot3\cdot1\cdot50\cdot49}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49}\\
&= \frac{4\cdot3}{52\cdot51},
\end{align}
so the formula I derived gives the correct result when $n=2.$
On the other hand, again setting $n=2,$ the allegedly "correct" answer comes out to
\begin{align}
\frac{^{48}C_{n-2}\cdot n\cdot 4\cdot 3}{^{52}C_n}
&= \frac{^{48}C_{2-2}\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 3}{^{52}C_2} \\
&= \frac{^{48}C_0\cdot 2\cdot 4\cdot 3}{\dfrac{52!}{2!50!}} \\
&= \frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 3}{52\cdot51},
\end{align}
which is exactly $4$ times the correct result.
So this formula is **incorrect**.

Now the question still remains why your first attempt did not get a correct answer.
(For the case $n=2$ you are still off by a factor of $2.$)
It seems to me that the problem is you are taking a sample space of all the
combinations of $n$ cards out of $52,$ where the same $n$ cards in a different sequence are considered the same outcome in the sample space.
But mixed in with this are two events that **depend on the sequence of the cards**,
namely, which of the two aces came first (which you assume are distinguishable events, although in the sample space of $^{52}C_n$ outcomes they are not), and the requirement that the second ace must be the $n$th card drawn.

Once you start mixing an "order doesn't matter" probability space with "order does matter" events, it can get hard to tease out what's actually going on.
But we can make one small adjustment to your sample space:
count it as $n\cdot{^{52}C_n}$ equally likely outcomes, each outcome defined by the $n$ cards that were drawn and the identity of the one card among the $n$ that was drawn last.

Now *that* is a suitable sample space within which you can count
$^{48}C_{n-2}\cdot 4$ possible combinations of cards that were **not** the last card drawn, multiply by the $3$ remaining possibilities for the card that was drawn last,
and thereby obtain the number of favorable outcomes that can be divided by $n\cdot{^{52}C_n}.$

Answer (score 2):

We must multiply the probability that exactly one ace is selected among the first $n - 1$ cards by the probability that the $n$th card selected is an ace.

We can select $n - 1$ of the $52$ cards in the deck in $\binom{52}{n - 1}$ ways.  If these cards include exactly one ace, we must select one of the four aces and $n - 2$ of the remaining $48$ cards.  Hence, the probability that the first $n - 1$ cards selected contain exactly one ace is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}}{\dbinom{52}{n - 1}}$$
Since $n - 1$ cards have been selected, there are $52 - (n - 1) = 53 - n$ cards left in the deck.  Three of these are aces.  Hence, the probability that the $n$th card is an ace given that exactly one ace has been selected among the first $n - 1$ cards is 
$$\frac{3}{53 - n}$$
Therefore, the probability that the second ace is the $n$th card selected is 
\begin{align*}
\Pr(\text{second ace is $n$th card selected}) & = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}}{\dbinom{52}{n - 1}} \cdot \frac{3}{53 - n}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}}{\dfrac{52!}{(n - 1)![52 - (n - 1)]!}} \cdot \frac{3}{53 - n}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}}{\dfrac{52!}{(n - 1)!(53 - n)!}} \cdot \frac{3}{53 - n}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}}{\dfrac{52!}{(n - 1)!(52 - n)!}} \cdot 3\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dfrac{52!n}{n(n - 1)!(52 - n)!}}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}\dbinom{3}{1}}{\dfrac{52!n}{n!(52 - n)!}}\\
& = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{48}{n - 2}\dbinom{3}{1}}{n\dbinom{52}{n}}
\end{align*}
so the stated answer is incorrect. That factor of $n$ should be in the denominator.

Your error was not accounting for the fact that the second ace must be in the $n$th position.  That requires two separate events.  There must be one ace among the first $n - 1$ cards and the $n$th card selected must be an ace.  While you accounted for this in your numerator, you did not do so in your denominator.

Comment: There is another answer flaming that n^2 should be in the numerator.... Now what's wrong there ???

Comment: @RandomAspirant  That is not what David K said.  He said that to get the correct answer, you must divide the stated answer by $n^2$.  In particular, his last paragraph states that the desired probability is $$\frac{\binom{48}{n - 2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{n\binom{52}{n}}$$ which is exactly what I got.  In short, David K and I agree, which is why I voted his answer up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty straightforward derivation of the generalized formula:

- Let $t$ be the number of all cards, they can be placed in $t!$ ways (order).
- Let $a$ be the number of all aces, they can be placed in $a!$ ways (order).
- Non-ace cards can be placed in $(t-a)!$ ways (order).
- Let $i$ be the ordinal number of the examined ace $i\in\{1,2, ..., a\}$.
- Let $n$ be the position of $i$th ace.
- There are $\binom{n-1}{i-1}$ possibilities for the first aces (positions).
- There are $\binom{t-n}{a-i}$ possibilities for the last aces (positions).

$$p_n=\frac{a! (t-a)! \binom{n-1}{i-1} \binom{t-n}{a-i}}{t!}$$

If $t=52$, $a=4$, $i=2$, then this formula gives the same results as the previously derived formula .

Comment: Equivalent to $\frac{\binom{n}{i}\cdot\binom{t-n}{a-i}}{\binom{t}{a}}\cdot\frac{i}{n}=\frac{\binom{t-a}{n-i}\cdot\binom{a}{i}}{\binom{t}{n}}\cdot\frac{i}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

**The Mistake**

Everything is unordered except the two aces: $\binom{52}{n}$ gives the number of unordered $n$ cards out of all cards, $\binom{48}{n-2}$ gives the number of unordered $n-2$ cards out of all cards except the aces, but $4\times 3$ gives you an ordered set of two aces.

**Quick Fix**

You can correct the mistake by introducing order to all terms. In the numerator, you have designated the $n$-th card to be one of the two aces, the remaining $n-1$ have $(n-1)!$ permutations. In the denominator, the $n$ cards have $n!$ permutation. So the corrected probability is:

$$
\frac{
\binom{48}{n-2}\cdot 4\cdot 3
}{
\binom{52}{n}
}
\times 
\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}
=
\frac{
\binom{48}{n-2}\cdot 4\cdot 3
}{
n\binom{52}{n}
}
$$

**Alternative Solution**

Draw (unordered) $n$ out of $52$ cards. The probability that there are exactly two aces is:

$$
\frac{\binom{48}{n-2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{n}}
$$

If we know that exactly $2$ out of $n$ cards are aces, and we order them, the probability that the $n$-th card is ace is:

$$
\frac{2}{n}
$$

Therefore, the probability you are looking for is simply a product of the two:

$$
\frac{\binom{48}{n-2}\cdot\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{n}}
\cdot
\frac{2}{n}
=
\frac{\binom{48}{n-2}\cdot 4\cdot 3}{n\binom{52}{n}}
$$

**Bonus**

From the alternative solution above, let $P_{i}$ be the probability that the $n$-th card is the $i$-th ace with $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. Easy to see the formula is:

$$
P_{i}=
\frac{\binom{48}{n-i}\cdot\binom{4}{i}}{\binom{52}{n}}\cdot\frac{i}{n}
\phantom{x}
\forall
\phantom{x}
i\in\{1,2,3,4\}
$$